# Chromium Render SPU tab stuck above VirtualBox task in Win10

Tags: ubuntu, windows-10, virtualbox

### Background:

I use Win10 and I run Ubuntu 15.10 on a virtual machine via VirtualBox.

Each time I run the VM, after about 1 hour, another tab is being added to its icon in the Win10 taskbar:

[image]

Note the two tabs --- The left is the Chromium Render SPU and the second is the VM with an Ubuntu environment.

### My problem:

This Chromium Render SPU tab inhibits my access to the Ubuntu VM. How can I remove it from there so that only the Ubuntu tab appears?

Any workaround or way to solve it will be accepted with much thanks and blessings! :)

### Note:

On the Internet, I found the advice to shut down the 3D acceleration, but if I am not wrong, it happened to me even when I disabled 3D acceleration for the VirtualBox Screen Display.

Comment: I'm getting this issue with RHEL 6.9 guest in Win 10 host, in July 2018. I have multiple desktops open, and it shows up in all of them, including those where no VM instance is open. I also have 3D acceleration enabled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's really doesn't answer the question but it seems to have been fixed somehow, maybe via an automatic update (either in VB, Win10, or both, yet I didn't recall encountering such an update in VB):

Throughout the web, I've repeatedly encountered the claim that turning off the 3D acceleration in VB fixed it (IIRC, for me it didn't).

Anyway, For about 7 months now I didn't encounter the problem.

---

### Update - 11/21/2016:

It is indeed unlikely, but **if** you are using Windows and keep experiencing this problem, **and if** all you need is the Ubuntu CLI terminal, consider installing [Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Subsystem_for_Linux) and using it as your Ubuntu-Bash environment instead. In WSL, as I get it, you use your GPU directly instead of any SPU.